# "Switch Case" and "If...else.." difference in Java/Java Card

Tags: java, javacard

Take a look at the following Java Card programs please. They seems equal in logic, but have different output in practice:

Simple incoming APDU command analyzer using `switch ... case` :

```
package testPack;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;

public class TestApp extends Applet {

    private TestApp() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength) throws ISOException {
        new TestApp().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = arg0.getBuffer();
        byte ins = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS];

        switch (ins) {
        case (byte) 0x80:
            ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x6901);
            break;
        default:
            ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x6902);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Same program using `if ... else ...` :

```
package testPack;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;

public class TestApp extends Applet {

    private TestApp() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength) throws ISOException {
        new TestApp().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = arg0.getBuffer();
        byte ins = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS];

        if (ins == (byte) 0x80) {
            ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x6901);
        } else {
            ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x6902);
        }
    }
}
```

As we know, in Java Card, APDU buffer header fields are considered as signed bytes. So I think in response of `00 80 00 00 00` APDU command, I must receive `69 02` for both above programs.

But this is the result:

First program:

```
Download Cap begin...
Download Cap successful.
Install Applet begin...
Install Applet successful.
Select Applet begin...
Select Applet successful.
Send: 00 80 00 00 00
Recv: 69 01
```

Second Program:

```
Download Cap begin...
Download Cap successful.
Install Applet begin...
Install Applet successful.
Select Applet begin...
Select Applet successful.
Send: 00 80 00 00 00
Recv: 69 02
```

Why the response is different?

Comment: What gives you `System.out.println(ins);` in both cases?

Comment: Could it be that you are running an older version of the second program, in which there was no cast on the value `0x80`?

Comment: @KolesnikovichDmitry It's a JavaCard program (And not Java program). There is no `System.out.println(ins);` method in Java Card APIs.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I run both above programs on a single smart card.

Comment: My question was not about the smart card. It was about the programs you are running - are you sure the second one was compiled with the `(byte)` or could it be an old version that you are running?

Comment: Can you try with `-128`. Bytes are signed in java. Maybe == goes by int? Normally should not be so.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ah, yes, I am sure that I installed the version with `(byte)` casting. I'm just retired that. There is something wrong with my card. I tried 3 different card, and only one of them has different response for above programs.

Comment: @Abraham, what type of cards are you using (as in what Java Card version, and do some of them support `int`)? If it helps: In my own Java Card code I would typically cast bytes to `short` and add `& 0xFF` before comparing to constant values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with java. This code:

```
byte ins = (byte) 0x80;

switch (ins) {
    case (byte) 0x80:
        System.out.println("switch matched");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("switch missed");
}

if (ins == (byte) 0x80) {
    System.out.println("if matched");
} else {
    System.out.println("if missed");
}
```

produces:

```
switch matched
if matched
```

The problem is somewhere else.

---

It is probably worth noting that `(byte) 0x80` results in `-128`.

Comment: You are right. There is something wrong with my smart card. I tried 3 different cards, only one of them has different responses for above programs.

Comment: @Bohemian I do not understand the point `(byte)0x80;` results is `0`. As `(byte)0x80 == -128`...see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement)

Comment: @vip did you read the last line of my answer? The purpose of this answer was to verify that OP's code actually does work *as is* (not to otherwise review it etc).

Comment: @Bohemian I don't get the point of your last line either since `(byte)0x80` is certainly not equal to zero (0) in Java.